# Como sumar el listado de números digitados?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, bucles

Lamentablemente no he dejado la novatada, estoy varado con una tarea el cual es la siguiente:

Hacer un programa el cual nos pida números hasta que se teclee un cero,  mostrar todos los números introducidos y la suma de todos los números introducidos.

```
   int[]num = new int[100];

   int contador=0,numeroactual=1,suma;
    while(numeroactual>=1 && contador<100){

        numeroactual=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
        num[contador]=numeroactual;
        contador++;
    }
     String msnumeros="";
        for(int i=0; i<contador; i++){
     msnumeros+=num[i]+"\n";
 }//aquí es donde estoy fallando. no ayo como sumar el listado de mis numeros digitados
      suma=num[contador]+contador;
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A continuación el listado de los numeros que digitaste:\n"+msnumeros);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Y la suma de los numeros que digitaste es: "+ suma);

}
```

}

Comment: porque suma esta afuera del for (TIP!!! TIP!!!!) ;)

Comment: Sugerencia no es necesario que realices un `for`, puedes ir sumando y llenando el string dentro del `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que guardar los números en un array, te daría un error si intentas intoducir mas de cien números. Para detenerte al entrar un cero debes mirar cada una de las entradas. El mismo `while` te sirve para realizar la suma y concatenar los valores introducidos.

```
    int contador = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    String msnumeros = "";
    int numeroActual = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero:"));

    while(numeroActual != 0){
        suma += numeroActual;
        msnumeros += numeroActual + " ";
        numeroActual = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero:"));
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"A continuacion el listado de los numeros que digitaste:\n"+msnumeros);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Y la suma de los numeros que digitaste es: "+ suma);
```

Comment: Tube la solución al frente de mis ojos y no se como no se me ocurrió antes. Muchas gracias